# Is the interior of a simple polygon, simply-connected?

Tags: geometry, terminology

This may be trivial, but I want to be sure I understand correctly:

Is it true that the interior of a [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) is always a simply-connected subset of the plane?

I.e, is it eligible for the Riemann mapping theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This follows from a stronger version of Jordan Curve Theorem, [Jordan–Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem).